# Textviews equal in height in Android ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-scrollview

I have a Android ScrollView with 3 TextViews:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="short text 1"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text"
                android:textSize="50dp"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="short text 2"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I want the following behavior:

- All TextViews have equal height - works
- If text does not fill out the screen, TextViews should fill out the entire screen (thus `fillViewport="true"`) - works
- If text is bigger than the screen, ScrollView starts to scroll, and TextViews are still equal in height (height of all TextViews equals highest TextView) - **does not work: TextView is clipped and ScrollView does not scroll.**

Here is how the screen looks like (TextView2 is clipped)
[image: That's how the screen looks like]

Comment: how do you want the textviews to behave, when the textview2's text is lengthy?

Comment: I want textViews2's text to be entirely seen, and all textViews should have the same length. So textView1 and textView3 should adapt textView2's height. Since the entire layout would be higher than the screen, I want the ScrollView to scroll.

Comment: Put `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for scroll view

Comment: Then the textView2 is still clipped. And it negates the effect of fillViewport="true"

Comment: @Damnum This question definition is wrong. Because if you want same height with `weight` then when second text size is big, obviously, it is clipped.

Comment: That's why I want the ScrollView to scroll if the text is too large.

Comment: @Damnum This is not possible. So, I think you have two options:- 1) give `wrap_content` height to textview inside scrollview  /(2) In LinearLayout, put three scrollview for all three textview, with `weight=1`. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use  `android:weightSum="3"`
in LinearLayout. On the basis of weightsum linearLayout divides into three equals parts in TextView, if textview uses  `android:layout_weight="1"`

Comment: Does not change the outcome. As you see in the screenshot, dividing into 3 equal parts already works, but the textView2 gets clipped and the screen won't scroll.

Comment: TextPaint paint = txtview2.getPaint();
                int wordwidth = (int) paint.measureText("a", 0, 1);
                int screenwidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
                int num = screenwidth / wordwidth;
                if (!expand) {
                    expand = true;
                    ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(desc_txt, "maxLines", num);
                    animation.setDuration(100).start();
                  


                }  the following code help to enchance the height of textview   as your text length.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

in textview and remove

> android:layout_weight="1"

```
      <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:text="short text 1"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```